# Photoshop with Wacom Intuos4: can't draw on low part of canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, corel-paint-shop-pro

After photoshop started and once it get focus, I can move stylus to low part of the screen. But if I switch to other app's windows, stylus can be moved to full screen.

I found a similar case on yotube, but with gimp, it can work although looks like wierd, and can be worked around by hide mouse cusor. The video is [Issue with Gimp and Intuos4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIMCvwTQkz4&noredirect=1&ytsession=g6xwYK6sT24Ajpf0HVmRRaSdcoB8OQ1yyMs2HE0G_GDVWjnPbgyqhGIpC4F7X6ANwff4RUrbFb_WCc5MoWE8CSacqrSRvnDQgBIjq58Fl-ncZTlWA50nr5HXpNKVwy2M6AWuSsWN8kKFUQLkGYnde8t617nmFWyI1GYckYNcjMUywsC2f8r4aj89NEGQ0aoi9H0ed6mc-mCpLEJ8Ow9jkbXwuJ5GTlhgbboPC2lr6g_sFIcRFiQZ3cqhNntDEs6bp3jOxqI-gNyb151wlhr9AaEpHNRt2fVYhC-HzNqGD5E)

With photoshop and painter, I have no luck. Do you know the solution? Any guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from a post in Adobe Forums: [Wacom tablet not servicing whole screen (Win 7)](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/621717)

Thanks god, it works. The win7's device manager cause the trouble.

> I just talked to Wacom Tech support. Using an Intuos 4, and Windows 7,
>   I was having some problems with CS5. He told me that the drivers
>   weren't completely installed. Here's what he told me to do.
>
> 1. Open the Start Menu
> 2. Open the Control Panel
> 3. If in category view, click Hardware and Sound
> 4. Under "Devices and Printers", click Device Manager
> 5. After opening the Device Manager, go down to "Mice and Other Pointing Devices" and click the drop-down arrow
> 6. If you see two "HID-Compliant Mouse" categories, click on both of them, and find the one that says "Wacom Virtual HD Driver" under
>      'Location'.
> 7. Once you have found the correct device, click on the Driver tab, and click the Update Driver button
> 8. Click on Browse My Computer for Driver Software
> 9. Click Browse -> Computer -> Program Files -> Tablet // OR type in the box " C:\Program Files\Tablet " and make sure you have the
>      "Include subfolders" option checked.
> 10. Click Next
> 11. And it should update itself.   I hope this clears things up. If not, try calling the Wacom Tech Support.
>       ~Kay